# Trying to make a jquery 'for' loop that adds div elements inside another div.

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='etch_a_sketch.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='etch_a_sketch.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        for(i=0; i<16; i++) {
            $('<div class="inner"></div>').appendTo('.outer');
    }
)};
```

Hello guys! I've tried looking for an answer here and elsewhere but with no luck. I'm trying to make a jquery 'for' loop that will dynamically make 16 div elements within an outer div container. The code looks sound to me but it's not working. I didn't post the CSS because it's irrelevant. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your parenthesis and braces seem to be imbalanced, check them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First. You have syntax errors. Last line `)};` should be `});` .

Next. No need to create a jQuery object twice (there's a syntax too - `}` should be `})`).

This line:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

does the exact same thing as this line:

```
$(function() {
```

**[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**

---

So, in summary, you should end up either with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(i=0; i<16; i++) {
         $('<div class="inner">blah</div>').appendTo('.outer');
    }
});
```

or this:

```
$(function() {
    for(i=0; i<16; i++) {
         $('<div class="inner">blah</div>').appendTo('.outer');
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmyra7ux/)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using jQuery, but haven't linked to the library. Add one of the following two lines (or download the file and link to that), depending on which version you want.

```
1.x snippet: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
2.x snippet: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also there are some problems with brackets not being closed. The following snippet shows it working without the additional anonymous function within the ready handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    $('<div class="inner">' + i + '</div>').appendTo('.outer');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 $(function() {
        var innerHTML=[];
        for(i=0; i<16; i++) {
            innerHTML.push('<div class="inner"></div>');
        }
        $('.outer').html(innerHTML.join(''));
 });
```

Please add jquery library to your page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready (function (){
    for (var i=0; i<=16; i++){
        $ ('.outer').html($('.outer').html()+"<div class='inner'></div>";
    }
});
```

The above is seriously simple. Try that first. My theory would be that appendTo is not working because the element doesn't already exist? But it should work anyway? Also, you don't need the anonymous function within another.

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest a better performance , it will speed up the process in case there is a lot of elements

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var innerDivs = ""; 
    for(i=0; i<16; i++) {
         innerDivs +='<div class="inner">blah</div>'; 

    }
    $('.outer').append(innerDivs); 
});
```

This will perform better because we will not have to access the DOM tree more than one time